# Difficulty in understanding the notation related from probability theory with game theory

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, bayesian-game, probability, information

The question that I have is a little technical and it has to do with the notation and the combination between some mathamatical properties in the probability theory of information economics.

Say $\mathcal{I}=(X,\mu)$ and $\mathcal{J}=(Y,\nu)$ are measurable probability spaces, where $\mu$ and $\nu$ denote the probability distributions over $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Then, we define $\phi:X\to\Delta(Y)$, where $\Delta(Y)$ is the simplex of $Y$. If the image of $\mu$ by $\phi$ is $\nu$ then it holds
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}\phi(x)(y)=\nu(y),\quad \text{where $\phi(x)(y)$ denotes the conditional probability $\phi(y|x)$}$$

Note that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures s.t. for every $x^i$ such that $\mu(x^i)>0$, then $p(x^i)\in\Delta(X^{-i})$ denotes the conditional probability of $\mu$ given $x^i$ over $X^{-i}$:
$$p(x^i)(x^{-i})=\mu(x^{-i}|x^i)=\frac{\mu(x^{-i},x^{i})}{\mu(x^i)}$$

Also, note that $\mu(x^i)$ stands for $\mu(\{x^i\}\times X^{-i})$.

To help you understand the notation, from game theory imagine that $i=\{1,2,3\}$, then $X=X^1\times X^2\times X^3= \{a^1,b^1\}\times\{a^2,b^2\}\times\{a^3,b^3\}$ and $x=(\underbrace{a^1}_{x^1},\underbrace{a^2}_{x^2},\underbrace{a^3}_{x^1})$

Even furhter, the following probabilities are defined. Let $r$ denote the ex-ante probability and $q$ the ex-post probability, they are defined as follows on $\Delta(Y^{-i})$:

$$r(x^i)(y^{−i})= P_{\phi}(y^{−i}|x^i),\quad\text{and}\quad q(y^i)(y^{−i})= P_{\phi}(y^{−i}|y^i)$$

for $P_{\phi}(x^i,y^i)>0$, where $P_{\phi}(x^i,y^i)=\mu(x^i)\phi^{i}(x^i)(y^i)$ denotes the probability induced on $X\times Y$ by $\mu$ and the transition probability $\phi$, then $r(x^i)$ and $q(y^i)$ are random vectors with values in $\Delta(Y^{-i})$ and $P_{\phi}(y^i|x^i)=\phi^{i}(x^i)(y^i)$ and $r(x^i)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x^i)}\phi^{-i}(x^{-i})$

$\textit{Question:}$ I struggle to understand how to calculate $r()$ and $q()$ with repsect to $\mu$ and $\nu$ as well. I can not clarify from the notation how are the ex-post and ex-ante probabilities connected with $\phi$, $\mu$, $\nu$ and $p$?

I think that $q(y^i)(y^{−i})$ equals to $\frac{\nu(y^{-i},y^i)}{\nu(y^i)}$, but I can not understand how to make the transition from $q(y^i)(y^{−i})= P_{\phi}(y^{−i}|y^i)=\dots=\frac{\nu(y^{-i},y^i)}{\nu(y^i)}$. Also what is the formula of $r(x^i)(y^{−i})$ and how it ends up to the result that $r(x^i)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x^i)}\phi^{-i}(x^{-i})$?

Also it seems that $p$ is the "backwards" version of $\phi$. Whereas $\phi$ tells you the likelihood of each value of $Y$ given the value of $X$, the function $p$ tells you, given $y$, the conditional probability it was produced by each $x$. So could I also claim that $P_{\phi}(x,y)=\nu(y)p(y)(x)=\mu(x)\phi(x)(y)$?

$\textit{Hint:}$ Keep in mind that the noation $f(x)(y)=f(y|x)$ in every situation and $f(x^i)$ is the conditional probability $f(x^i)(x^{-i})=f(x^{-i}|x^{i})$

Comment: What text does this come from?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker this one https://econ-papers.upf.edu/papers/169.pdf

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker more precisely pages 4 and 5 contain all this information.

Comment: @Giskard is it ok if I am going yo edit one or 2 more questions here? I do not want to write a new question, since the new questions will be implied within the same framework

Comment: @nav89 In this case I think you should copy info from the Q, not edit answered Q's.

Comment: `@Giskard ok i will do this right now

Comment: @Giskard check this one when you have time https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47679/mechanisms-of-communication-in-game-theory

Comment: @Nav89 I think perhaps you meant to address this to users tdm or Michael Greinecker?

Comment: @Giskard of course but i can not tag them...can you tell me how?

Comment: @Nav89 The same way you tagged me...? (only one tag is allowed per comment)

Comment: @Michael Greinecker check this one when you have time https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47679/mechanisms-of-communication-in-game-theory

Comment: @tdm check this one when you have time, you hace a better understanding in this notation than me...it seems so confusing to me https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47679/mechanisms-of-communication-in-game-theory?noredirect=1#comment76764_47679

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that ${\cal I} = ((X^i)_i, \mu)$​ and ${\cal J} = ((Y^i)_i, \nu)$​ are two information structures.

An Interpretation mapping for player $i$​​ is a mapping $\phi^i: X^i \to \Delta(Y^i)$​ so it associates with every $x^i$​ a distribution over $Y^i$​.

Let $x^i \in X^i$​. Then $\phi^i(x^i)$​ is a distribution over $Y^i$​ so $\phi(x^i)(y^i)$​ is the probability of this distribution attached to outcome $y^i$​.

Then for $x = (x^1, \ldots, x^I)$ we can define:
$$
\phi: \prod_i X^i \to \Delta\left(\prod_i Y^i\right)
$$
Such that for all $x = (x^1,\ldots, x^I)$ and $y = (y^1,\ldots, y^I)$ we have the product probability measure:
$$
\phi(x)(y) = \phi^1(x^1)(y^1) \cdot \phi^2(x^2)(y^2) \cdot \ldots \cdot \phi^I(x^I)(y^I)
$$
We have that an interpretation $\phi= (\phi^i)_i$​ is **consistent** if for every $x \in \prod_i X^i$ and $y \in \prod_i Y^i$:
$$
\mathbb{E}_\mu \phi(x)(y^i) = \nu(y),\\
\leftrightarrow \sum_{x \in X} \phi(x)(y) \,\, \mu(x) = \nu(y)
$$
Now define $\phi(x)(y) \mu(x) = P(x,y)$​. Then the sum of $P(x, y)$ over all $x$ and $y$ equals 1:
$$
\sum_x \sum_y P(x,y) = \sum_x \sum_y \phi(x)(y)\,\, \mu(x) = \sum_y \nu(y) = 1
$$
Also the marginal distributions satisfy:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_x P(x,y) = \sum_x \phi(x)(y)\mu(x) = \nu(y),\\
&\sum_y P(x,y) = \sum_y \phi(x)(y) \mu(x) = \mu(x) \sum_y \phi(x)(y) = \mu(x).
\end{align*}
$$
So $P(x,y)$​​​ act as a joint probability distribution over $\prod_i X^i \times \prod_i Y^i$ with marginals $\nu$ and $\mu$. Then $\phi(x)(y) = \dfrac{P(x,y)}{\mu(x)}$ which  is the same as the conditional probability $\phi(x)(y) = P(y|x)$​​.

We can write the marginals $P(y) = \nu(y)$​ and $P(x) = \mu(x)$​. Also, let $P(y^i)$ be the marginal distribution of $P$ with respect to $y^i$, $P(x^i)$ the marginal distribution of $P$ with respect to $x^i$ and so on.

Then we can define:
$$
q(y^i)(y^{-i}) = P(y^{-i}|y^i) = \dfrac{P(y^i, y^{-i})}{ P(y^i)}.
$$
And:
$$
r(x^i)(y^{-i}) = P(y^{-i}|x^i) = \dfrac{ P(x^i, y^{-i})}{ P(x^i)}.
$$

> I think that $q(y^i)(y^{−i})$ equals to $\frac{\nu(y^{-i},y^i)}{\nu(y^i)}$

I think you are correct. Notice that $P(y^i, y^{-i}) = \nu(y^i, y^{-i})$ and $P(y^i) = \sum_{y^{-i}} P(y^i, y^{-i}) = \sum_{y^{-i}} \nu(y^i, y^{-i}) = \nu(y^i)$ so indeed (by Bayes rule):
$$
q(y^i)(y^{-i}) = \dfrac{P(y^i, y^{-i})}{P(y^i)} = \dfrac{\nu(y^i, y^{-i})}{\nu(y^i)} = \nu(y^{-i}|y^i)
$$

> Also what is the formula of $r(x^i)(y^{−i})$ and how it ends up to the result that $r(x^i)=\mathbb{E}_{p(x^i)}\phi^{-i}(x^{-i})$?

The comuputation for this expression is a bit more involved. First:
$$
\begin{align*}
P(x^i, y^{-i}) &= \sum_{x^{-i}, y^{i}} P(x^i, x^{-i}, y^i, y^{-i}),\\
&= \sum_{x^{-i}, y^{i}} \phi(x^i, x^{-i})(y^i, y^{-i}) \,\, \mu(x^i, x^{-i}),\\
&=\sum_{x^{-i}, y^i} \mu(x^i, x^{-i}) \left[\left(\prod_{j \ne i} \phi^j(x^j)(y^j)\right)\phi^i(x^i)(y^i) \right],\\
&=\sum_{x^{-i}} \mu(x^i, x^{-i}) \left(\prod_{j \ne i}\phi^j(x^j)(y^j)\right) \underbrace{\sum_{y^{i}} \phi^i(x^i)(y^i)}_{=1},\\
&=\sum_{x^{-i}} \mu(x^i,x^{-i})\,\, \phi^{-i}(x^{-i})(y^{-i}),\\
\end{align*}
$$
Next one has,
$$
P(x^i) = \sum_{x^{-i}} P(x^i, x^{-i}) =  \sum_{x^{-i}} \mu(x^i, x^{-i}) = \mu(x^i)
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
r(x^i)(y^{-i}) &= \dfrac{P(x^i, y^{-i})}{P(x^i)},\\
&= \sum_{x^{-i}} \frac{\mu(x^i, x^{-i})}{\mu(x^i)} \phi^{-i}(x^{-i})(y^{-i}),\\
&= \sum_{x^{-i}} p(x^i)(x^{-i})\,\, \phi^{-i}(x^{-i})(y^{-i}),\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{p(x^i)} \phi^{-i}(x^{-i})(y^{-i})
\end{align*}
$$

#### Additional questions and answers

> 1. Does it mean that the product measure is always translated to a conditional probability?

No, that is why the authors impose the defintion that the interpretation should be **consistent**.

> 2. Have you seen any textbook that has the same notation as in here?

No. In my opinion, the notation is rather inconvenient to work with ;-)

> 3. Why $P(y^i, y^{-i}) = \nu(y^i, y^{-})$.

Let $y = (y^i, y^{-i})$ then:

$P(y^i, y^{-i}) = P(y)$ which is the marginal distribution of $P(x,y)$ with respect to $y$. Condition $(1)$ shows that this is equal to $\nu(y) = \nu(y^i, y^{-i})$.

> 4. How did you figure out $P(x^i, y^{-i}) = \sum_{x^{-i}, y^i} P(x^i, x^{-i}, y^i, y^{-i})$.

Similar as in point 3, $P(x^i, y^{-i})$ is the marginal distribution $P$ with respect to $(x^i, y^{-i})$, so you have to 'integrate out' $(x^{-i}, y^i)$. As these are finite, this amounts simply to taking the sum.

Comment: wow...and thanks! I couldn't ask for moore...so let me check if there is anything that i can not understand for a little more...clarification....

Comment: 1. You say by the product probability measure we have:

$$\phi(x)(y)=\phi^1(x^1)(y^1)\dot\phi^2(x^2)(y^2)\dot \dots\phi^I(x^I)(y^I)$$
and also $\phi(x)(y)=P(y|x)$ does it mean that the product measure is always translated to a conditional probability?

2. Have you seen any textbook that has the same notation as in here?

3. Why $P(y^i,y^{-i})=\nu(y^i,y^{-i})$? I think that you will say by definition, but I am missing something that makes me not seeing it.

4. How did you figure out $P(x^i,y^{-i})=\sum_{x^{-i}, y^{i}} P(x^i, x^{-i}, y^i, y^{-i})$, $\sum_{y^{i}} \phi^i(x^i)(y^i)=1?$

Comment: thank you in advance!

Comment: @Nav89 I added my answers to my response above. Heres the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) on how marginal distributions are computed.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: So, to sum up,the probability $\phi$ denotes the transition probability of moving from one state of a system $\mathcal{I}$ into another state to $\mathcal{J}$. The extra condition that is needed is the assumption of consistency, right? But how do we translate consistency here?

And my other question is why $\sum_{y^i}\phi^i(x^i)(y^i)=1$, my understanding is teh follwing:

$$\sum_{y^i}\phi(x^i)(y^i)=\phi^1(y^1)(y^1)+\phi^2(y^2)(y^2)+\dots +\phi^I(y^I)(y^I)=\phi^1(y^1|y^1)+\phi^2(y^2|y^2)+\dots+\phi^I(y^I|y^I)=\phi(y|y)=1$$

Comment: @Nav89 we have that $\phi(x^i)$ is a probability distribution over $Y^i$ so if you add up the probababilities, you get 1: $\sum_{y^i \in Y^i} \phi(x^i)(y^i) = 1$.

Comment: so what i wrote is wrong i guess :P but i undes=rstand what you say i am ok

Comment: check this one when you have time, you hace a better understanding in this notation than me...it seems so confusing to me

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47679/mechanisms-of-communication-in-game-theory